# VueJS - Filtering array of objects and comparing the $route.params with the property value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

I am trying to sort the arrays using JavaScript such a way that i want to display the property values only when it is equal to the $route.params.my_id.

Here is my response that i get from the API ie Array of objects:

```
 [
      {
        "my_id": 2,                            <-- index[0]
        "employee_name": "John", 
        "salary: "26000",           
        "experience: "5"     
      },
      {
        "my_id": 3,                            <-- index[1]
        "employee_name": "Sam",
        "salary: "46000",             
        "experience: "15"          
      },
       {
        "my_id": 1,                            <-- index[2]
        "employee_name": "Raj",
        "salary: "16000",
        "experience: null           
      }
   ]
```

In component1 i am setting the `$route.params.my_id = company.my_id.toString()` where the company.my_id is taken from the response of API. So, the company.my_id gets 1, 2 or 3 respectively depending on the selected route.

In component2 i am using `company[$route.params.my_id].employee_name` as a option for select button. Here i have used $route.params.my_id as the index value so it can 1, 2 or 3.

But here is the question, the index starts from zero, so it is [0], [1] or [2]. So if `$route.params.my_id is 2` then in component2 `company[2].employee_name` it should show the my_id 2's information but rather it shows my_id 1's info as index[2] contains my_id 1's info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Do not rely on sorting to achieve this

It was a clever idea, but it will only work well if the `my_id` values form a good sequence, i.e. *always* consisting of the integers from 1 (or 0) upwards in some permutation.

Do not rely on this being the case.

It will help you in your debugging if you change the `my_id` values to something that is *nothing* like an array index, e.g. "idx", "idy", "idz". This way, when your code breaks, it is much more obvious what is going wrong.

#### Filter the array, rather than sorting it

You could try this, inside the `.then( result => {  ...  })`

```
 this.company= result.data.filter(company => company.my_id === $route.params.my_id )[0]
```

This extracts just the one company entry of interest. Try it out.

#### Better to do error checking

If the above works in principle, you should improve the code to test for two possible error states. First, there may be no companies matching the id. Secondly, there may be more than one company matching it.

```
const matchingCompanies = result.data.filter(company => company.my_id === $route.params.my_id )
if (matchingCompanies.length===0){ /* Error action for no matches */}
if (matchingCompanies.length>=2){ /* Error action for multiple matches */}
// Now we know there is exactly one match
const matchingCompany = matchingCompanies[0];
```